# Remove spaces when writing to CSV using CSVWriter in java

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

I am reading from table and writing to `CSV` file using `CSVWriter` in JAVA. My delimiter is `'control-A'` . But one column is having spaces in comments. So how to remove that spaces from value while writing to CSV file.
My code is

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("query");
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filePath + "File_writerCSV.csv"),'\u0001');
writer.writeAll(rs,false);
writer.close();
```

Comment: Why do you not use a delimiter that is not appearing in your data?

Comment: We can use. But that is comment column.. might be any character they will use. If any way to remove that then that is better

Comment: If the comma is not important you can always replace it using `string.replace(',', ' ')`. But I think you should rather use an delimiter like `$$$$$`

Comment: Did you try to call writer.setUseTextQualifier(true) ?

Comment: I am using opencsv library

Comment: The correct technique is not to remove the comma, which is part of the data, but to quote the cell.

Comment: editing the question, now i am using different delimiter, but now problem is with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpenCsv this should not be a problem: it will automatically quote values as necessary, i.e. if one of the values you write is `some,comment` OpenCsv will actually write `"some,comment"` (enclosed in qoutes). All standard csv; nothing you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

other way is if a value contains ',' character put that value in quotes.
of example if value is 
BMW,AUDI,MERc --> convert it into "BMW,AUDI,MERC". so it will be considered 1 entity.

```
String s = "as,as,as";
        if(s.contains(","))
        {
            s="\""+s+"\"";
        }
```

Comment: The library will automatically do this if needed.